# Using JScript in powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

Reading through the documentation for powershells add-type it seems you can add JScript code to you powershell session.

Firstly is there a decent example of how this is done and secondly can you use this to validate normal javascript code (as I understand JScript is the MS implementation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a good starting point

[PowerShell ABC's - J is for JavaScript](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/powershell-abcs-j-is-for-javascript) (by Joe Pruitt)

Here is a code snippet from the above article:

```
function Create-ScriptEngine()
{
  param([string]$language = $null, [string]$code = $null);
  if ( $language )
  {
    $sc = New-Object -ComObject ScriptControl;
    $sc.Language = $language;
    if ( $code )
    {
      $sc.AddCode($code);
    }
    $sc.CodeObject;
  }
}
PS> $jscode = @"
function jslen(s)
{
  return s.length;
}
"@
PS> $js = Create-ScriptEngine "JScript" $jscode;
PS> $str = "abcd";
PS> $js.jslen($str);
4
```

Comment: Thanks that was almost spot on

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple json parser: https://gist.github.com/octan3/1125017

```
$code = "static function parseJSON(json) {return eval('(' +json + ')');}"
$JSONUtil = (Add-Type -Language JScript -MemberDefinition $code -Name "JSONUtil" -PassThru)[1]

$obj = $JSONUtil::parseJSON($jsonString)
```

`-PassThru` will give you an object (actually two objects; you want the second one) that you can use to call the functions.

You can omit it if you want, and call the function like this:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.JSONUtil]::parseJSON($jsonString)
```

but that's a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Jscript.net http://www.functionx.com/jscript/Lesson05.htm (or VisualBasic, F# ...)  It has to compile into a dll.

```
Add-Type @'
 class FRectangle {
   var Length : double;
   var Height : double;
   function Perimeter() : double {
       return (Length + Height) * 2; }
   function Area() : double {
       return Length * Height;  } }
'@ -Language JScript


$rect = [frectangle]::new()
$rect

Length Height
------ ------
     0      0
```